# Update react setState with mouse Event values

Tags: reactjs

I can update state for a moment then it just freezes, can I not set state so often?

The aim is to simply show the cursor position to the user.

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';

const Inspector: React.FC = () => {

  const [state, setState] = useState({
    offsetX: 0,
    offsetY: 0,
  });

  const canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
  if (canvas) {
    canvas.addEventListener(
      'mousemove',
      (event) => {
        setState((prev) => ({
          ...prev,
          offsetX: event.offsetX,
          offsetY: event.offsetY,
        }));
      },
      false
    );
  }

  return (
    <div className='inspector'>
      <div className='inspector--container'>
        <div className='inspector--description'>Cursor X</div>
        <input type='text' value={state.offsetX} />
      </div>

      <div className='inspector--container'>
        <div className='inspector--description'>Cursor Y</div>
        <input type='text' value={state.offsetY} />
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export { Inspector };
```

Comment: https://reactjs.org/docs/render-props.html
This might help you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are doing a state update in the Render part. So while rendering you update the state, which causes another Render, which causes another and goes on recursively leading to out of memory. React will catch the same and avoid this from happening, but no more state updates will be triggered after this.

use `useEffect` hook to do state update and you should be fine. Also, you should clear the event listener once component unmounts.

```
const Inspector: React.FC = () => {

const [state, setState] = useState({
   offsetX: 0,
   offsetY: 0,
});
useEffect(()=> {
  const canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
  if (canvas) {
    canvas.addEventListener(
    'mousemove',
    (event) => {
       setState((prev) => ({
         ...prev,
         offsetX: event.offsetX,
         offsetY: event.offsetY,
        }));
      },
    false
   );
  }
 })

 return (
   <div className='inspector'>
     <div className='inspector--container'>
       <div className='inspector--description'>Cursor X</div>
       <input type='text' value={state.offsetX} />
  </div>

  <div className='inspector--container'>
    <div className='inspector--description'>Cursor Y</div>
    <input type='text' value={state.offsetY} />
  </div>
</div>
)};

export { Inspector };
```

Comment: I should have known this, your answer works perfectly, thank you